# filtering json with different head value in ruby

Tags: json, ruby

I have this kind of hash

```
{"1515599671"=>
  {"Path"=>"images/1515599671.jpeg",
   "Tags"=>
    {"Anger"=>0,
     "Disgust"=>0,
     "FaceDetected"=>1,
     "Fear"=>0,
     "Happiness"=>0,
     "LargeFaceDetected"=>0,
     "MotionDetected"=>0,
     "Neutral"=>0,
     "Sadness"=>0,
     "Surprise"=>0}},
 "1525357331"=>
  {"Tags"=>
    {"Anger"=>0,
     "Disgust"=>0,
     "FaceDetected"=>0,
     "Fear"=>0,
     "Happiness"=>0,
     "LargeFaceDetected"=>0,
     "MotionDetected"=>0,
     "Neutral"=>0,
     "Sadness"=>0,
     "Surprise"=>0}},
 "1525357336"=>
  {"Tags"=>
    {"Anger"=>0,
     "Disgust"=>0,
     "FaceDetected"=>0,
     "Fear"=>0,
     "Happiness"=>0,
     "LargeFaceDetected"=>0,
     "MotionDetected"=>0,
     "Neutral"=>0,
     "Sadness"=>0,
     "Surprise"=>0}},
 "1525357341"=>
  {"Tags"=>
    {"Anger"=>0,
     "Disgust"=>0,
     "FaceDetected"=>0,
     "Fear"=>0,
     "Happiness"=>0,
     "LargeFaceDetected"=>0,
     "MotionDetected"=>0,
     "Neutral"=>0,
     "Sadness"=>0,
     "Surprise"=>0}},
 "1525357346"=>
  {"Tags"=>
    {"Anger"=>0,
     "Disgust"=>0,
     "FaceDetected"=>0,
     "Fear"=>0,
     "Happiness"=>0,
     "LargeFaceDetected"=>0,
     "MotionDetected"=>0,
     "Neutral"=>0,
     "Sadness"=>0,
     "Surprise"=>0}},
 "1525357448"=>
  {"Path"=>"images/1525357448.jpeg",
   "Tags"=>
    {"Anger"=>0,
     "Disgust"=>0,
     "FaceDetected"=>1,
     "Fear"=>0,
     "Happiness"=>0,
     "LargeFaceDetected"=>0,
     "MotionDetected"=>0,
     "Neutral"=>0,
     "Sadness"=>0,
     "Surprise"=>0}},
 "1525357449"=>
  {"Path"=>"images/1525357449.jpeg",
   "Tags"=>
    {"Anger"=>0,
     "Disgust"=>0,
     "FaceDetected"=>1,
     "Fear"=>0,
     "Happiness"=>0,
     "LargeFaceDetected"=>0,
     "MotionDetected"=>0,
     "Neutral"=>0,
     "Sadness"=>0,
     "Surprise"=>0}}}
```

In which many of the values don't have a `Path` and few of them have a path, I want to filter this hash to get a hash in which there will be only those values which have Path within them, I have tried to do .each and map but its not working on it? any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: _Sidenote:_ the object you have posted is a ruby hash, not a JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [select](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/select) on Hash for this:

```
hash = {"1515599671"=>{"Path"=>"images/1515599671.jpeg", "Tags"=>{"Anger"=>0, "Disgust"=>0, "FaceDetected"=>1, "Fear"=>0, "Happiness"=>0, "LargeFaceDetected"=>0, "MotionDetected"=>0, "Neutral"=>0, "Sadness"=>0, "Surprise"=>0}}, "1525357331"=>{"Tags"=>{"Anger"=>0, "Disgust"=>0, "FaceDetected"=>0, "Fear"=>0, "Happiness"=>0, "LargeFaceDetected"=>0, "MotionDetected"=>0, "Neutral"=>0, "Sadness"=>0, "Surprise"=>0}}, "1525357336"=>{"Tags"=>{"Anger"=>0, "Disgust"=>0, "FaceDetected"=>0, "Fear"=>0, "Happiness"=>0, "LargeFaceDetected"=>0, "MotionDetected"=>0, "Neutral"=>0, "Sadness"=>0, "Surprise"=>0}}, "1525357341"=>{"Tags"=>{"Anger"=>0, "Disgust"=>0, "FaceDetected"=>0, "Fear"=>0, "Happiness"=>0, "LargeFaceDetected"=>0, "MotionDetected"=>0, "Neutral"=>0, "Sadness"=>0, "Surprise"=>0}}, "1525357346"=>{"Tags"=>{"Anger"=>0, "Disgust"=>0, "FaceDetected"=>0, "Fear"=>0, "Happiness"=>0, "LargeFaceDetected"=>0, "MotionDetected"=>0, "Neutral"=>0, "Sadness"=>0, "Surprise"=>0}}, "1525357448"=>{"Path"=>"images/1525357448.jpeg", "Tags"=>{"Anger"=>0, "Disgust"=>0, "FaceDetected"=>1, "Fear"=>0, "Happiness"=>0, "LargeFaceDetected"=>0, "MotionDetected"=>0, "Neutral"=>0, "Sadness"=>0, "Surprise"=>0}}, "1525357449"=>{"Path"=>"images/1525357449.jpeg", "Tags"=>{"Anger"=>0, "Disgust"=>0, "FaceDetected"=>1, "Fear"=>0, "Happiness"=>0, "LargeFaceDetected"=>0, "MotionDetected"=>0, "Neutral"=>0, "Sadness"=>0, "Surprise"=>0}}}

hash.select { |key, value| value['Path'] }    # Returns key-value pairs only with 'Path' set in its value. Modify the condition to remove empty strings, if you need to
 => {"1515599671"=>{"Path"=>"images/1515599671.jpeg", "Tags"=>{"Anger"=>0, "Disgust"=>0, "FaceDetected"=>1, "Fear"=>0, "Happiness"=>0, "LargeFaceDetected"=>0, "MotionDetected"=>0, "Neutral"=>0, "Sadness"=>0, "Surprise"=>0}}, "1525357448"=>{"Path"=>"images/1525357448.jpeg", "Tags"=>{"Anger"=>0, "Disgust"=>0, "FaceDetected"=>1, "Fear"=>0, "Happiness"=>0, "LargeFaceDetected"=>0, "MotionDetected"=>0, "Neutral"=>0, "Sadness"=>0, "Surprise"=>0}}, "1525357449"=>{"Path"=>"images/1525357449.jpeg", "Tags"=>{"Anger"=>0, "Disgust"=>0, "FaceDetected"=>1, "Fear"=>0, "Happiness"=>0, "LargeFaceDetected"=>0, "MotionDetected"=>0, "Neutral"=>0, "Sadness"=>0, "Surprise"=>0}}}


# Question update
hash.select { |key, value| value['Path'] && value['Tags'] && (value['Tags']['Anger'] == 1) }    # Select those with 'Path' set and 'Tags.Anger' with value 1
 => {}     # You don't have any such objects in your example
```

Comment: Okay I am extending it a little bit, If After getting that `Path` ones, As you see there are few tag values, And If I want to get all those where You can say Tag's Anger has value 1?

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`iteraptor`](https://github.com/am-kantox/iteraptor) gem for that purpose:

```
require 'iteraptor'
hash = { ... }

keys = hash.iteraptor.select(/\APath\z/).keys
#⇒ ["1515599671", "1525357448", "1525357449"]

hash.select { |k, _| keys.include? k }
```

Comment: I requested for a json with only Path values included

Comment: Then `hash.iteraptor.select(/\APath\z/)` would do. Also, again, it’s **not** a JSON by any mean, it’s a ruby hash.

Comment: Okay, do you really think for this purpose its good to use an external lib?

Comment: It seems you were unable to come to solution yourself; that usually means that using a `gem` is a good way to go. If you don’t want to use an external lib, feel free to copy-paste the solution from there (you might notice it’s not as trivial.)